# Using forEach on Documents in MongoDB

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I am following [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/perform-read-operations/). 
I am unable to understand why the following would mean print each Document in JSON format. That is how `forEach` works and why the method name `apply` is run for each `Document`

```
Block<Document> printBlock = new Block<Document>() {
       @Override
       public void apply(final Document document) {
           System.out.println(document.toJson());
       }
};

collection.find(new Document()).forEach(printBlock);
```

Comment: you need to read about functional interfaces in java 8. The `Block` interface acts as `Consumer`

Answer (score 9):

This is because the [find](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#find-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) operation return a [MongoIterable](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoIterable.html) which has declared a [forEach](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoIterable.html#forEach-com.mongodb.Block-) method for java-7 [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html?is-external=true) which has no `forEach` method at all.

So you can call the [forEach](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoIterable.html#forEach-com.mongodb.Block-) method on a [MongoIterable](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoIterable.html) as in your question. In java8, the [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html?is-external=true) includes the [forEach(Consumer)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) operation. if you use `forEach` with inlined Lambda Expression or Method Reference Exception in java8, you must to cast the lambda to the explicit target type, for example:

```
collection.find(new Document())
          .forEach( it-> System.out.println(it.toJson())); // compile-error

// worked with inlined lambda expression
collection.find(new Document())
          .forEach((Consumer<Document>) it -> System.out.println(it.toJson()));


collection.find(new Document())
          .forEach((Block<Document>) it -> System.out.println(it.toJson()));

// worked with method reference expression
collection.find(new Document())
          .forEach((Consumer<Document>) printBlock::apply);

collection.find(new Document())
          .forEach((Block<Document>) printBlock::apply);
```

For more details about lambda expression you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the javadoc of [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) method, it takes [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) as argument. `Consumer` is nothing but a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) that has just one method. forEach method internally calls the single method

In your case `Block` is a functional interface that has just one method `apply` that consumes one argument and returns nothing, i.e. a `Consumer`

You could have implemented the same using lambda expression, without a need to implement `Block`

```
collection.find(new Document()).forEach(doc-> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

Comment: What I understand is this is Java 8 way. Is there a below Java 8 way to do the same ?

Comment: Is doc the current item ?